# Recursive query in MySQL( find direct and indirect supervisor of Bob )?

Tags: mysql, sql, recursive-query

There is one problem that I encountered and that can we solved using recursive query but my code is giving error in **MySQL**.

**Problem is as follow:**

```
person    supervisor
Mary       Susan
David      Mary
Bob        Alice
Alice      David
```

**Find all supervisor(direct and indirect) of Bob?**

Here is my solution for above question:

```
create recursive view find_all(person,supervisor,depth) as
(
        select person,supervisor,0 as depth from employee as e
        where e.person = 'Bob'
        union all
        select in1.person,out1.supervisor,in1.depth+1
        from find_all as in1,employee as out1
        and in1.supervisor = out1.person
        and in1.depth<=100
        
);
```

**And for output:**

```
select * from find_all;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach.  Just create a normal view.  The view contains the recursive `WITH` clause.

```
CREATE VIEW find_all(person,supervisor,depth) AS
WITH RECURSIVE cte1 AS (
        SELECT person, supervisor, 0 AS depth
          FROM employee AS e
         WHERE e.person = 'Bob'
         UNION ALL
        SELECT in1.person, out1.supervisor, in1.depth+1
          FROM cte1 AS in1, employee AS out1
         WHERE in1.supervisor = out1.person
           AND in1.depth <= 100
     )
SELECT * FROM cte1
;
```

Result:

```
select * from find_all;

+--------+------------+-------+
| person | supervisor | depth |
+--------+------------+-------+
| Bob    | Alice      |     0 |
| Bob    | David      |     1 |
| Bob    | Mary       |     2 |
| Bob    | Susan      |     3 |
+--------+------------+-------+
```

**Alternate form:**

The `<from clause>` contains a `<table reference list>` which is a comma separated list of `<table reference>, <table reference>, ...`.  This produces `cross join` behavior. We then use a `WHERE` clause to effectively `inner join` these table references.

It's commonly suggested to use a single `<table reference>`, for several good reasons, which can contain a `<joined table>`.  The second `UNION` term below contains an example of a `<joined table>`.

A couple of advantages are ease of identifying (and not accidentally forgetting) the corresponding `<join condition>` and easier to change between join types.

```
CREATE VIEW find_all(person,supervisor,depth) AS
WITH RECURSIVE cte1 AS (
        SELECT person, supervisor, 0 AS depth
          FROM employee AS e
         WHERE e.person = 'Bob'
         UNION ALL
        SELECT in1.person, out1.supervisor, in1.depth+1
          FROM cte1     AS in1
          JOIN employee AS out1
            ON in1.supervisor = out1.person
         WHERE in1.depth <= 100
     )
SELECT * FROM cte1
;
```

In this case, the depth logic is not really part of the `<join condition>`.  It's really a subsequent filter of the rows produced by the `join`.

The difference is seen when, for example, we have a `left outer join`.  We don't want that logic to just generate more nulls for the right table columns.  We want that logic to produce no further rows when `depth` is exceeded.

Comment: I would recommend to use modern join syntax, just for clarity.

Comment: @TheImpaler Agreed.  I used the OP's syntax intentionally, more to keep focus on the only needed change.  I'll add the other form as well.